# Image classification with Sift features and Knn?

Tags: image-processing, classification, sift, knn

Can you help me waith Image classification using SIFT feature?

**I want to classify images based on SIFT features:**

- Given a training set of images, extract SIFT from them
- Compute K-Means over the entire set of SIFTs extracted form the
  training set. the "K" parameter (the number of clusters) depends on
  the number of SIFTs that you have for training, but usually is around
  500->8000 (the higher, the better).
- Now you have obtained K cluster centers.
- You can compute the descriptor of an image by assigning each SIFT of
  the image to one of the K clusters. In this way you obtain a
  histogram of length K.
- I have 130 images in training set so my training set 130*K
  dimensional
- I want to classify my test images ı have 1 images so my sample is 1*k
  dimensional. I wrote this code knnclassify(sample,training
  set,group).

I want to classify to 7 group. So, `knnclassify(sample(1*10),trainingset(130*10),group(7*1))`

**The error is:** The length of GROUP must equal the number of rows in TRAINING. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the docs:

> CLASS = knnclassify(SAMPLE,TRAINING,GROUP) classifies each row of the
>       data in SAMPLE into one of the groups in TRAINING using the nearest-
>       neighbor method. SAMPLE and TRAINING must be matrices with the same
>       number of columns. GROUP is a grouping variable for TRAINING. Its
>       unique values define groups, and each element defines the group to
>       which the corresponding row of TRAINING belongs. GROUP can be a
>       numeric vector, a string array, or a cell array of strings. **TRAINING
>       and GROUP must have the same number of rows.**

What this means, is that `group` should be 130x1, and should indicate which group each of the training samples belong to.  `unique(group)` should return 7 values in your case - the seven categories represented in your training set.
If you don't already have a group vector which specifies which categories which image falls into, you could use `kmeans` to split your training set into 7 groups:

```
group = kmeans(trainingset,7);
knnclassify(sample, trainingset, group);
```